# How many ways are there to form a 5  × 3  rectangle from squares of side lengths 1, 2  and 3 ?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, contest-math, tiling, dynamic-programming

**"How many ways are there to form a 5  × 3  rectangle from squares of side lengths 1, 2  and 3  ?"**

Above is a question from **SEAMO**(**S**outh **E**ast **A**sian **M**ath **O**lympiad). I tried to solve it but failed. I thought to make some combinations and thought of some kind of pattern. But couldn't.
BTW this is a SEAMO 2020 Grade 5-6 problem. So please think of easy solutions like some kind of patterns, observations, etc.

**ANS:**

> \begin{align} ANS = 28 \end{align}

Please Help.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What have you tried? It's not too bad listing out all of the ways. $\quad$ Hint for better approach: Starting from the right, consider the largest square that touches the right-edge. Hence, create a linear recurrence and show that the answer is 28 (if I'm correct).

Comment: To take help , please show your work

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you mean a 'Dynamic Programming' type recurrence relation? BTW the answer is 11

Comment: Linear recurrences can be considered a subset of DP, so technically yes. However, this is much much easier than a (potentially complicated) DP. $\quad$ Like Bulbsaur said, show your work. A $ 5 \times 3$ isn't that hard to get to (esp if there are just 28 possibilities).

Comment: I was actually thinking of a Grid DP.

Comment: Are you counting symmetric tilings twice? That is, these two tilings are 180 degree rotations of each other, do they count as two or one?
$$
\begin{matrix}A&A&A&B&B\\A&A&A&B&B\\A&A&A&C&D\end{matrix}
\qquad
\begin{matrix}C&D&A&A&A\\B&B&A&A&A\\B&B&A&A&A\end{matrix}
$$
I ask because I started counting assuming they would be different, but I am getting more than $11$ tilings.

Comment: @MikeEarnest What is A, B, C, and D?

Comment: @TrisanuDas Each letter corresponds to a square. The $A$'s group together to make a $3\times 3$, the $B$'s group together to make a $2\times 2$, and the $C$ and $D$ are each a $1\times  1$.

Comment: I think anwser is 20.

Comment: If you must use at least one square of each size the answer is less than 11, otherwise it is greater than 11, and maybe the greater than 20

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu you are right I forgot one posibility. It must be 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ a_n$ be the number of ways to form a $ n \times 3$ rectangles using squares of length $1, 2, 3$.

Goal: Find a recurrence relation for $a_n$.

Hint: Starting from the right, consider the largest square that touches the right-most edge.

> $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}, a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 3.$

Corollary: Determine $a_5$.

> $a_5 = 28$.

Comment: Thanks @CalvinLin for the recurrence relation. I first used your hint to find out the function , then got it correct(Same Function). And the given answer(11) was wrong

Answer (score 1):

If we take only first row with lenght 5 and generate all possible variants, that add up to 5, we get 13 distinct posibilities:

1. 1 1 1 2 | x3          5. 1 1 3 | x2          9. 2 1 2 | x1
2. 1 1 2 1 | x2          6. 1 3 1 | x1         10. 2 2 1 | x1
3. 1 2 1 1 | x2          7. 3 1 1 | x2         11. 2 3 | x1
4. 2 1 1 1 | x3          8. 1 2 2 | x1         12. 3 2 | x1             13. 1 1 1 1 1 | x8

each variant, then has it's number of possibilities which add up to 28.

Comment: It's little bit greater than 20. My answer is the same

Comment: FYI I've undeleted my solution to show how the linear recurrence approach works without having to list out all possible variants.